# design for interchangeable use of lightweight and full objects

Tags: c#, inheritance, dry

I am working in a system that uses an interface and class structure similar to this:

```
interface ILw                // a lightweight interface definition

class Medium : ILw

class FullA : Medium         // full class definitions
class FullB : Medium

class LwA : ILw              // lightweight class definitions
class LwB : ILw
```

Within the system I encounter objects that could be full or lightweight, and so have functions that expect the *ILw* interface.  The problem I run into with this design is that there are more data and methods that need to be shared between the full and lightweight versions of the objects than is defined in *ILw*.  So I find myself needing to do something like this:

```
if (myvar is FullA)
{
   (myvar as FullA).MyFunction()
} 
else
{
   (myvar as LwA).MyFunction()
}
```

where *MyFunction()* is implemented separately in each *FullA* and *LwA* and may work on identical data structures.  I want to eliminate this code duplication.

With my C++ background it seems to be a typical case for multiple inheritance; i.e., define a class *SharedA* for the data and methods that both need and add it to the parent list of *FullA* and *LwA*.  But I need some guidance to help think through this in a C# and interfaces world.  Is there an accepted pattern to solve this problem?

Thank you.

**UPDATE:**

With the help of the comments received so far, I've been able to refactor for a better design with 1) an intermediate interface requiring an aggregate for shared data and 2) an extension class for methods to work on this data.  Ideally these (data and methods) would be joined in the same construct.  I feel like mate-in-1 is on the board and I just don't see it.

```
public interface ILwBase { }

class Medium : ILwBase { }

public class LwDataA
{
    static private int _count = 0;
    public int id;
    public LwDataA() { id = ++_count; }
}

public interface ILwA : ILwBase 
{
   LwDataA ExtData { get; }
}

public static class ExtLwA
{
   public static void MyFunction(this ILwA o) 
   {
      Console.WriteLine("id = " + o.ExtData.id); 
   }
}

class LwA : ILwA
{
   private LwDataA _extData = new LwDataA();
   public LwDataA ExtData { get { return (_extData); } }
}

class FullA : Medium, ILwA
{
   private LwDataA _extData = new LwDataA();
   public LwDataA ExtData { get { return (_extData); } }
}

class Program
{
   static void Main()
   {
      ILwA a1 = new FullA();
      ILwA a2 = new LwA();

      a1.MyFunction();
      a2.MyFunction();
   }
}
```

This allows what I need with only two lines of duplicate code between LwA and FullA. And it removes the need to call through an aggregate property (my previous edit) or implement wrappers around an aggregate.

Hopefully this clarifies what I am trying to achieve.  Is this the best solution?

Comment: If you need to treat FullA and LwA differently, can they **truly** be said to be coded to the same interface? Maybe your interface is broken by design and needs to be made better/more comprehensive?

Comment: @Patashu Many times I don't care whether I am working with a "full" object.  What I need to be able to do in these cases is work with a small subset of data and methods that are common between the two.

Comment: If the interface does not do that for you (define all methods that are common between the two) your interface is broken.

Comment: I'm not really understanding your problem... why isn't MyFunction() defined in the Interface?  couldn't just having virtuals in Intermediate solve the problem of specializing your "interface" in subclasses?

Comment: MyFunction() is not defined in the interface because it only pertains to the "A" classes, not to the "B" classes.

Comment: @smertrios and Patashu - I put an update on the tail of my post to reflect your input.

Comment: In your example, the MyFunction() signature is declared in both concrete classes.  In this case, all you need is a different implementations through polymorphism (virtual/abstract.)  Am I still missing something?

Comment: @smertrios yes, I think you are missing the issue of the Intermediate class that is used as a parent to the "full" classes.  CodingWithSpike showed a similar structure using an abstract class, but as the answer stands right now has multiple inheritance and does not compile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following our comments exchange, you problem now is seen in a different light than the original post. You can't have directly what multiple inheritance would have given you. But there are various ways you can get very close.

Variant 1: Trick your special classes that need `MyFunction()` into receiving it as an extension method. To accomplish this, you need a "differentiator"; in my example that is the ILwA interface. Note that it has to define another commonality, not `MyFunction()`. A getter (or a setter) will do. Limitation here is that MyFunction doesn't have access to private members.

```
//instead of the lightweight interface (but use interface if it makes more sense)
abstract class LwBase 

abstract class HwBase : LwBase

public interface IADiff { int APropTrick { get; } }

// lightweight class definitions
class LwA : LwBase, IADiff
class LwB : LwBase

// full class definitions
class FullA : HwBase, IADiff
class FullB : HwBase

public static class AExtensions
{
    public static void MyFunction(this IADiff o)
    {
        // impl.
    }
}
```

Variant 2: use a common class that provides implementation of `MyFunction()` and "redirect" to it:

```
abstract class LwBase 

abstract class HwBase : LwBase

public interface IADiff { int MyFunction(); }

public class AConcr : IADiff //implemenst Myfunction()

// lightweight class definitions
class LwA : LwBase, IADiff
{
    private AConcr a = new AConcr();

    public int MyFunction() { return a.MyFunction(); }
}
class LwB : LwBase

// full class definitions
class FullA : HwBase, IADiff
{
    private AConcr a = new AConcr();

    public int MyFunction() { return a.MyFunction(); }
}
class FullB : HwBase
```

Variant 3: I stumbled on [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/10072/Simulated-Multiple-Inheritance-Pattern-for-C) as I was researching your question. I can't quickly say if it's a viable option, but it certainly provides ideas.

Credits: I am heavily borrowing from [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515886/design-pattern-to-use-instead-of-multiple-inheritance), as well as using [this nice site](http://www.dofactory.com/Patterns/Patterns.aspx) as a reference.

Comment: where are you defining MyFunction() in this?  If I define it in an abstract class then I'm still not sure how to solve the problem without multiple inheritance due to the Intermediate class.

Comment: You're stating `where MyFunction() is implemented separately in each FullA and LwA`, so you define MyFunction in ILwA and both LwA and FullA are required to implement it. I've updated my answer.

Comment: yes, that is how I have the code now...  MyFunction() is implemented identically in FullA and LwA.  But I'm trying to get rid of the duplication if possible.

Comment: thank you.  I've taken your advice and incorporated a combination of Variants 1 & 2.  My "UPDATE" in the question is updated again.

Comment: thank you, too. It was interesting! `Is this the best`-IMO there's nothing wrong with it, as long as it works for your purpose - they all come with their advantages and limitations.

Answer (score 1):

To share implementation you can have them both inherit from an `abstract`:

```
interface ILwBase                // a lightweight interface definition
interface ILwA : ILwBase
interface ILwB : ILwBase

class Intermediate : ILwBase

abstract class AbstractA : ILwA {
  void MyFunction() {...}
}

class LwA : AbstractA, Intermediate
class LwB : Intermediate 

class FullA : AbstractA
class FullB : ILwB
```

Read more about [Abstract Classes (on MSDN)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k535acbf%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: An abstract class solves the issue of sharing implementation.  But the remaining problem is using the Intermediate class:  `class LwA : AbstractA, Intermediate` won't compile because it is multiple inheritance.

Comment: Oh sorry, I was thinking that `Intermediate` was also an interface. My fault.

Comment: yeah, starting it with *I* confuses.  Should have called it Middle.