# how can is it possible to inherit from multiple classes in c#

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have 2 classes `base1` and `base2`

```
   public class base1
    {
public base1(int I, string s)
{
}
      public void f1()
    {
    // code
    }
    public void f2()
    {
    // code
    }
    public void p()
    {
    // code
    }

    }
    public class base2
    {
public base2(int x)
{
}
      public void f3()
    {
    // code
    }
    public void f4()
    {
    // code
    }

    protected void f5()
    {
    // code
    }

    }
```

I need to implement 5 classes that derive from both of them
but there is no multiple inheritance in `c#`....so how can I do it?-one class `base1`i can`t change. with the second one i can expirement.so the only idea i have is to make it  to be `interface`? but both classes constructors have arguments!so it is not possible to make a interface
may be you have better ideas...

Comment: Interesting as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515886/design-pattern-to-use-instead-of-multiple-inheritance

Comment: Like many have mentioned, multiple inheritance is not preferable... it's actually pretty dangerous.  When I studied C++, I learned about the Diamond problem of inheritance.  Basically, you may end up with a situation where you're calling a method of the same name that exists in both base classes.  There's a solution to it using a virtual keyword, but it's all a mess in my eyes.

Comment: @Sajeetharan-no.look ataupdate about constructor

Answer (score 1):

`Multiple inheritance`  had been ruled out for C# after careful study. Yes, `Interfaces` are indeed the recommended way to go. That is unless you can use `Composition`. It really depends on what behaviour and what knowledge the classes are supposed to model!

Answer (score 0):

There is no better idea, as you said, in C# you can inherit only from one class .

You should extract an interface from your classes and inherit from these interfaces .

Answer (score 0):

I recommend to extract the functionality to interfaces, and then, to deal with the parameters in constructor, create a new method inside the interfaces called, Load or something, that takes the parameters that the constructor takes right now.

```
public Interface IBase1
{
    public void Load(int param1, string param2);

    public void f1();

    public void f2();

    //The rest of methods...
}
```

And the same with the second one!

Then you class will inherit from this interface, and will fill the Load method.

```
public class MyClass : IBase1
{
    public void Load(int param1, string param2)
    {
    // Implementation
    }
}
```

I hope this helps for you