# Java design issue: Inheriting from multiple abstract classes

Tags: java, abstract

I have a design problem in Java. I have

- an abstract class `Feature` which represents features (machine learning), and
- an abstract class `Normalizable` which inherits from `Feature` and represents features which can be normalized.

A concrete feature can be an instance of either `Feature` or `Normalizable`.

I would like to introduce an abstract class called `Probablity` which inherits from `Feature` and represents features on which some sort of probability calculations can be done.

An actual feature should either be an instance of `Feature` (not normalizable and no probability) or it should be an instance of `Normalizable`, or `Probability` or both.

The problem now is that an actual feature cannot inherit from both `Normalizable` and `Probability`.

How can I solve this issue? I think using interfaces is not the solution because all of the mentioned classes contains implementations.

Comment: Using interfaces is the only solution that come to my mind if you can't design a class structure. Otherwise you may go to a design pattern like strategy, Where the type of the algorithm/implementation used has to be determined at runtime.

Comment: It helps to _name_ your classes to clarify your intent. For instance, it makes little sense to call a subclass of `Feature` a `Probability`. It's better to call it say `ProbabilisticFeature`. To further help you, can you identify some methods with appropriate names on each of these classes?

Comment: @ImeshaSudasingha But interfaces cannot have actual implementations. So I have to push the implementations in my actual classes (implementing the interfaces) which creates lot of duplicate code.

Comment: So you have classes (abbreviated) F,N,P with $P\to F\gets N$ (and possibly more, all inheriting from F), do I get this right? And then yo want to have instances of F with any combination of abilities from those? http://stackoverflow.com/a/2516100/4142984 might help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class `NormalizablePrbability.java` Use `Composition` and have `Probability.java` and `Normalize.java` as fields in newly created class `NormalizablePrbability.java`. You can extend `NormalizablePrbability.java` from `Feature.java` and override the methods and in each method you can provide the combined features of both `Probability.java` and `Normalize.java`.

Now you can have your concrete classes which can extends from `Feature.java` or `Normalize.java` or `Probability.java` or `NormalizablePrbability.java`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Your assumption is not correct (and my explanation was not so good). Probability.java inherits from Feature.java but not from Normalizable.java. An object can be a subtype of Normalizable, Probability or both. The problem is when the class should be a subtype of both.

Comment: @BlackHawk I am sorry for understanding your question wrongly, I have made the corrections in my answer, hope it helps.