# Multiple Inheritance is not supported in C# so how can I get this to work?

Tags: c#, inheritance, interface, multiple-inheritance, composition

I have created two DataGridViews with different purposes and I wanted to combine them together. I had not realized before that you cannot inherit from multiple base classes.

I have looked at various other Stack Overflow questions and found a common theme of people recommending Interface or Composition solutions. I have tried to apply these concepts to my situation but they just don't seem to fit quite right.

To start, here is the structure I was hoping for...

---

RowSelectionDataGridView - DataGridView that selects entire rows and has options for easy styling of colors and such

DragAndDropDataGridView - RowSelectionDataGridView that lets the user click row(s) to drag on top of another row and have the row(s) moved where they were dropped

ContextMenuDataGridView - RowSelectionDataGridView that shows a ContextMenuStrip above the right clicked on row for things such as copy, paste, delete, etc

CombinedDataGridView (not actual name) = DragAndDropDataGridView and ContextMenuDataGridView that would let user drag and drop and also have a context menu strip on right click

```
                                        DataGridView                          
                                             ▲                                
                                             |                                
                                             |                                
                                  RowSelectionDatatGridView                   
                                             ▲                                
                                             |                                                                
                        _____________________|_____________________           
                       |                                           |          
                       |                                           |          
             DragAndDropDataGridView                   ContextMenuDataGridView
                       ▲                                           ▲          
                       |                                           |          
                       |___________________________________________|          
                                             |                                
                                             |                                
                                             |                                
                                    CombinedDataGridView
```

---

If I were to implement...

**Interfaces:** 
My understanding is that ContextMenuDataGridView and DragAndDropDataGridView would need to become interfaces and then CombinedDataGridView would inherit from both of these. I don't see the point of this because then all of the logic would just have to be implemented in the CombinedDataGridView anyways. What would the major benefit of this be? Or what am I misunderstanding about this?

**Compositions:** My understanding is that CombinedDataGridView would then have instances of DragAndDropDataGridView and ContextMenuDataGridView in it. That doesn't seem to make sense at all for this.

How do I need to structure my classes to get my desired functionality?

Comment: _and I wanted to combine them together._ Um, yes, but what made you think MI would be a good and useful way to do that??

Comment: @TaW I had assumed it would be easy once I had the different DataGridViews created but was unpleasantly surprised to receive the error when I tried `public class CombinedDataGridView : DragAndDropDataGridView, ContextMenuDataGridView`. After seeing that error it makes sense why I couldn't do this, but I'm not sure what the alternative approach is. I had figured you could just easily derive from two base classes that share the same base class and it would get both sets of functionality.

Comment: Step one: Rid yourself of the ooop (overdone oop) thinking that everything is defined be what it is. Instead most is defined by what it can do; which are the methods you give a nice name and group into, yes, Interfaces.. And, yes, they must be inplemented in each particiapting class. Which is not so much tedious but the chance to do it properly each time..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: [*Honey don't*](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-M-mr-0wSw)

---

**1. Multiple Inheritance (MI)**

Inheritance is based on the notion `'A'` **is a** `'B'` but with some additions or changes.

This makes sense quite often.

MI however, which extends this idea to `'A'` **is both** a `'B'` **and** a `'C'` runs into many problems conceptually, esp. when the two 'parents' are either too different (e.g.: both a 'vehicle'  and 'food') or when they are too similar.. One reason why the latter can introduce issues are 'clashes' , that is fields (or methods) both parents have..; now, which will be used in `'A'`: `'B.field1'` or `'C.field1'` ? Without always qualifying, this gets rather confusing.

When A. Hejlsberg started to design C# he had not only desigend the extensions to go from *Pascal* to *Turbo Pascal* and also the highly successful *Delphi* framework. He had also implemented *Microsoft's Java* compiler. So he knew the issues MI would bring and decided that the benefits MI really offers (multiple polymorphism and reusability) can all be realized with `Interfaces`..

**2. Interfaces**

An `Interface` is not an object nor does it contain any code or any data. It is a **contract** that promises that any class that is adorned with this `Interface` will provide a certain set of features.

The best way to understand and appreciate this concept is to study the `.Net` framework. Do have a look at [IComparable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.icomparable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). It is the base for sorting all types of things in their own special way as long as they are `IComparable` (and, I think `IEnumerable`); yet all those sorts can rely on specific comparison methods to be there.. This allows you to implement **generalized** functionality **once** and **reuse** it again and again.

One often used example is about shapes. Using inheritance to build up an inheritance chain or tree that includes circles, triangles, rectangles, squares will lead to all sorts of clashes.. But adding an `IDrawable` interface is natural and will allow you for example to to collect them in a `List<IDrawable>` which you can then enumerate..

Another example is [`ISerializable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.iserializable%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) which also provides (or rather promises) a general service implemented in specialized ways.

**3. Your case**

I'm sorry to say, but your case is best 'solved' by abandoning the whole idea.

Not only is it problematic because both parents are **visual** controls, which makes MI clashes especially likely. In fact both are **the very same**, i.e. both are `DataWindows`! This is a MI nightmare, as every single field will clash!

**4. How to solve it**

- The most natural way is to abandon the whole MI approach and do it like the framework itself does it: Introduce a feature as soon in the inheritance chain as it makes sense. Along with the feature we introduce a `'bool CanDoOrHasFeature'` property and all is well.

The most ovbious examples are all those `'AllowUserToXYZ'` properties `DataGridView` has..

Do not fear that this makes the program bloated: The class definition is loaded only once! (And, of course, if you want to provide the logic the code must be written/loaded once anyway.)

- Another option are helper classes; you can write a `ReorderElements` class and let those controls register to it which you want to supply with this feature. I have a `ControlMover` class and let controls I want to make moveable subscribe to its services..

Comment: Your explanation of why to avoid multiple inheritance assumes non-virtual MI. Virtual MI avoids most of the drawbacks you described (but may add some of its own). Of course, C# doesn't support that either, and your suggested alternative is a good way to avoid the need for MI here.

Comment: Interesting comment. [Here is a starter for further reading on C++ VMI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_inheritance).

Comment: @TaW I was actually originally doing something very much like what your solution is. I was hoping there was a way to separate out the functionalities and some answers here gave ways that seemed promising. Unfortunately they didn't really end up being all that effective for my situation and actually just added extra code.

Answer (score 0):

I have been asked this question during an interview.
You can use a design pattern.
[Design pattern to use instead of multiple inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2515886/design-pattern-to-use-instead-of-multiple-inheritance)

Comment: This seems like it could maybe work, but I'm having a hard time converting from that questions' accepted answer to my situation. Which one of my classes should be the interface?

Comment: Neither. The Intefaces contain the (declaration of the) features, not any other part of the classes like fields etc..

Comment: So what features would my interface have? Sorry, I'm not being lazy, I'm just really not getting it. I've been toying with this problem all day. I've never implemented an interface before.

Comment: Well, without going into the coding details of hooking up events, the names you chose are are good start: IRowDragable and IContextMenueEnabled are a bit long but to the point..

Comment: @TaW I think I might be getting it finally! Your interface names sparked something in my head. So the interfaces aren't actually inheriting from DataGridView but are something that says any object inheriting IRowDragable needs to implement these things. And IRowDragable isn't even tied to DataGridView at all. Is this about right?

Comment: @BlakeThingstad This is one way you could do it.  This way you don't have to repeat all of the logic.  Without seeing your actual code I can't create something better but here you go. https://dotnetfiddle.net/i6p1Z5

Comment: @thinklarge Thank you for the very detailed implementation! I think this will work perfectly! I'll get back to you and let you know if I got it to work. When I first looked at it I had a concern about each datagridview having their own DataTable and if one datagridview changed their own DataTable then the others would remain unaffected. I think this is fine though because they would all reference the same DataTable. Right?

Comment: @Blake: _And IRowDragable isn't even tied to `DataGridView` at all. Is this about right?_ Yes it is; a `ListView` or some other control  with dragable elements could implement the __same__ `Interface`. But see my answer! I wouldn't really use `Interfaces` here because the whole question is __all__ about `DGV`s, ie about the same base class. Implementing the `Interfaces`  for each would be a drag, even if you could 'outsource' much of it to a common service class..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want by switching from an "is-a" mentality to a "has-a". Instead of making different classes that by their type behave differently, make a single class that can accept different behaviors in a list. The behaviors are then used to make the rest of the functionality work. (Your classes *have* behaviors instead of *being* a thing that denotes only one behavior).

I could only offer more detail if I could see your code. Among all the various design patterns you should find some that will make clearer to you how to achieve what you want. One pattern to start with is Decorator. There are others that could be useful.